# Change color of polar chart rings using anycharts?

Tags: javascript, html, anychart

Is it possible to change color of individual rings in polar chart using `anychart` charting library?

***Code:***

```
drawPolarChart() {

      // create data set on our data
      var chartData = {
        rows: [
          ['Flow', 10],
          ['Energy', 20],
          ['Commitment', 100],
        ]
      };
  
      // sort data by X - // set series type - // disable y-axis - // set x-scale
      this.chart.sortPointsByX(true).defaultSeriesType('column').yAxis(true).xScale('ordinal');
  
      // set max y-axis values.
      this.chart.yScale().maximum(100).ticks().interval(10);

      // set 50th percentile to red dotted ring.
      
  
      // set chart data
      this.chart.data(chartData);
  
      // set title margin
      this.chart.title().margin().bottom(20);
  
      // set stack mod
      this.chart.yScale().stackMode('value');
  
      // set tooltip settings
      this.chart.tooltip().valuePostfix('%').displayMode('union');
  
      // set chart container id
      this.chart.container('chartContainer');
  
      // initiate chart drawing
      this.chart.draw();

  }
```

I intend to change the ring labeled '50' to any color of my choice?

[image]

***Edit***
Similar to [this](https://playground.anychart.com/api/core/axes/_samples/anychart.core.axes.Polar.stroke_set) but I am unable to make it work for other specific rings.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Color_Management)?

Comment: Yes, I tried using yMinorGrid to set the color but it is changes color of all rings to red for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the charts you can use custom theme option,
https://docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Themes#out_of_the_box_themes

Out of the box Themes can be located either at [Themes Section at AnyChart CDN](https://cdn.anychart.com/) or in the AnyChart Downloadable Package, these themes change the look, feel and layout of every chart, map, gauge, treemap or stock chart. You are free to use and modify these themes as you want. To use any of these themes you need, just with any [External theme](https://docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Themes#external_themes) reference the proper file in HTML document and then apply theme by name:

```
<head>
<!--Link to the files with out of the box themes -->
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/themes/2.0.0/coffee.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/themes/2.0.0/dark_blue.min.js"></script>
<script>
  anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  // data
  var data = [
    ["Department Stores", 637166],
    ["Discount Stores", 721630],
    ["Men's/Women's Specialty Stores", 148662],
    ["All other outlets", 90000]
  ];

  // apply coffee theme
  anychart.theme(anychart.themes.coffee);

  // apply dark blue theme
  // anychart.theme(anychart.themes.darkBlue);

  // create and display chart
  var chart = anychart.bar();
  chart.bar(data);

  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
 });
</script>
</head>
```